# integrate data from another dataset conditional on a categorical column in R

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have two datasets. One has course difficulty, and the other has a list of students and the courses that they took. Here are the sample datasets:

```
library(tidyverse)
courses <- tibble(course_name = c("Adv Operating", "Art Intel", "CS Net"),
            dif = c(1, 5, 10))


student_records <- tibble(student = c("Corey", "Sibley", "Justin"),
                  spring_14_1 = c("Adv Operating", "Adv Operating", "CS Net"),
                  spring_14_2 = c("Art Intel", NA, "Art Intel"))
```

I want to make a new column called spring_14_dif that adds the difficulties of their courses. Something that looks like this:

```
answer <- tibble(student = c("Corey", "Sibley", "Justin"),
                  spring_14_1 = c("Adv Operating", "Adv Operating", "CS Net"),
                  spring_14_2 = c("Art Intel", NA, "Art Intel"),
                  spring_14_dif = c(6, 1, 15))
```

I've tried doing case_when, but I can't crack it. Ideally, tidyverse answers are appreciated, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

student_records %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("spring"), names_to = "Term", values_to = "Course") %>%
  left_join(courses, by = c("Course" = "course_name")) %>%
  group_by(student) %>%
  summarise(spring_14_dif = sum(dif, na.rm = T)) %>%
  left_join(student_records)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  student spring_14_dif spring_14_1   spring_14_2
  <chr>           <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      
1 Corey               6 Adv Operating Art Intel  
2 Justin             15 CS Net        Art Intel  
3 Sibley              1 Adv Operating NA
```